# RCaller: prevent automatic error printing

Tags: java, r, rcaller

I'm using `RCaller` to execute some analysis on a data frame within my `Java application`. More specifically, I want to run `Coarsened Exact Matching` using the `CEM` library of `R`.

As far as `CEM` is concerned, it returns some data about the mathching, if any match is found. Otherwise (no match found) it fails.

When I call the `runAndReturnResult` method from my `Java application`, if `CEM` fails inside `R`, `RCaller` automatically prints on my `Java application's console`, all the code that I added to my `RCode` instance.

Is there a way for preventing this printing? I mean, I want to ignore the cases in which no match is found and move forward, without printing messages on my console.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this:

- `RCaller` is using `java.util.logging.Logger`, so you need to add a `logback.xml - file` for disabling the output of the `logger`.
- use `tryCatch({})` inside `R`  so that your `R code` won't break -> won't trigger any errors in `Java`.

I would recommend the second solution.

**update:**

you have to add an `error - block`

```
mat <- tryCatch({
   cem(treatment = "c_CLUSTER", data = df, drop = dp))
 }, error = function(e) {
    NULL # or do something else
 }, finally = {
 })
```

And if you want to ignore all the `warnings`, wrape your `method call` in `suppressWarnings(<method-call>)`

Or you can also add an `warning - block` to the `tryCatch - block`

Comment: Thank you Paul for your suggestion. I think that `tryCatch({})` is what I'm looking for, but unfortunately I'm a bit far from having it working. I tried with the following code but it goes on printing errors: `result <- tryCatch({mat <- cem(treatment = "c_CLUSTER", data = df, drop = dp))}, finally = {})`

Comment: the code you suggested perfectly works in `R`: I tried it with `RStudio` and `mat` is `NULL` everytime the match fails. Anyway, errors are still printet in my java application's consolle. If I print the exception this is what I get `rcaller.exception.ParseException: Can not handle R results due to : rcaller.exception.ParseException: Can not parse output: The generated file C:\Users\ROBERT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Routput1530072892585177778 is empty
 at rcaller.RCaller.runAndReturnResult(RCaller.java:429)`.

Comment: I'm also using `RCaller` and I'm doing it like this: `result <- suppressWarnings(tryCatch({<methodCall>}, error = function(e){-1}))` and I'm reading in `Java` the `result` variable and if it's `-1` I know that there happened something bad. It's a self-convention.

Comment: RCaller can't write `NULL` to file and that's why it remains empty and you get the error.